# Can't install rvm

Tags: 13.04, ruby, rails

I want to install RVM:

```
ubuntu@ext:~$ rvm
The program 'rvm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
ubuntu@ext:~$ sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby-rvm
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It seems it is only available on 12.04: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-rvm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To install RVM stable with ruby, run the following command:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

<sub>**Note**: There is a backslash before curl. This prevents misbehaving if you have aliased it with configuration in your ~/.curlrc file.</sub>

<sub>[*Source*](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)</sub>

Comment: Right, don't use the ubuntu package. It was something of a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```